# Does the collapse of a state need to be necessarily included within the set of postulates of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-states, foundations

> *When an operator is measured on a quantum state of a system, the state collapses into an eigenstate of the operator being measured.*

Should something of this sort be necessarily included within the set of postulates of quantum mechanics? Please give the reason for your answer. For example, I think it is not possible to exclude this because 'state preparation' requires collapse.

Comment: Are you looking for theoretical arguments/mathematical consistency? or experimental evidence?

Comment: Do you mean that we only have half of Born’s rule? We observe outcome $\lambda_n$  with probability $|\langle n|\psi\rangle|^2$ but that the state doesn’t subsequently collapse to $|n\rangle$?

Comment: It depends on the interpretation. It is not a neccesary postulate, in general

Comment: @RaúlAparicioBustillo I have added one sentence at the end. With that in mind, it appears to be necessary.

Comment: @innisfree Yes. Is something like  "half of the Born rule" as you explained enough? See the last sentence in my post.

Comment: Many worlds + decoherence doesn't postulate collapse nor the Born rule, so the answer to your question seems to be no – it doesn't have to (some interpretations include it, some don't).

Comment: Interpretations which do not respect the mathematical structure of quantum mechanics are not in fact interpretations of quantum mechanics.

Comment: The trouble is only with the *word* 'collapse'. But the principle that, after a measurement, the quantum state that describes a physical system has to be updated to take the measurement result in consideration is indeed part of the postulates of QM, and *you just cannot use QM at all* if you do not apply it - you just cannot compute anything, and so cannot perform any experiment, whitout applying this principle, How it is called should not matter, but matters only because what this principle physically states is still unclear, and that is the measurement problem.

Comment: I am not a devotional followers of MWI, but it have no problems for interpretation. Many worlds you can watch, of course. When worlds reunify, all the information of every different world is erased. It is not a sympathetic interpretation, but, are there another one?  Science is something that explain the facts, not our conception of the world. I would prefer other one. Still waiting

Answer (score 1):

This was essentially the projection postulate:

- the effect of a measurement is represented by the action of a projection operator.

The projection postulate was originally expressed by von Neumann for observables with discrete values. It was extended by Lüders to continuous observables. It is valid for measurement of a single quantum particle, in which states are labeled by measured quantities, but it is too restrictive to describe all numerical quantities used in the classical description of nature. Classical quantities can also be described by the expectation of a Hermitian operator, where a measurement of the expectation does not induce the collapse of the wave function. For example in qed it is possible to describe the classical $A$ field as the expectation of the the photon field operator (although only derivatives are strictly observable).

A projection operator is a linear operator $P$ from a vector space $V$ to itself
such that
$$P^2=P $$
Thus, for any vector $|p\rangle$ in the range $P(V)$, we have that $|p\rangle = P|f\rangle$ for some vector $|f\rangle$. Then,
$$ P|p\rangle =P^2|f\rangle = P|f\rangle = |p\rangle $$
So that the action of a projection operator on a state is to create an eigenstate (collapse) and a repeat measurement gives the same result. The corresponding observable operator with eigenstates $|p\rangle$ and eigenvalues $p$ can be written
$$\sum |p\rangle p \langle p| $$ 
For a general state $|f\rangle$ it is easily seen using the Born rule that the expectation of the observable is
$$\sum \langle f|p\rangle p \langle p| f \rangle$$

In a more general axiomatic treatment, one postulates that observables are given by Hermitian operators, $A$, with expectations given by $\langle f| A |f\rangle$, and derives the Born rule when probabilities can be given for the observation of particular states.

Comment: maybe show them how a projection mathematically collapses psi . But other than that I agree

Comment: I'm curious: how is it " too restrictive to describe all numerical quantities used in the classical description of nature."?

Comment: I gave the particular example of the classical electromagnetic field.